# how to i show so many comments in single forum post

Tags: laravel, comments, laravel-5, forum

this is my comments table

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign( 'post_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'posts' )->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('comments');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

this is my post table

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

on my post model i give hasMany

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

on my comments model i give belongsToo

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\comment;
use App\post;
use Crypt;


class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $posts = post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
        return view('post.index', compact('posts'));
    }

public function create(){

    return view('post.create');
}

public function store(Request $request){

    $post = new post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->save();
    return redirect()->route('rules');
}

public function show($title){

$post = post::where('title', $title)->first();
$comments = post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

return view('post.show', compact('post', 'comments'));
}

public function storecomment(request $request){

    $comment = new comment;
    $comment->post_id = Crypt::decrypt(Input::get('post_id'));
    $comment->comments = $request->comments;
    $comment->save();

    return redirect()->route('rules');
}
}
```

i have view foreach but i see all comments in every post
what i type on my view to show comments with post_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting comments on every post

```
@foreach($post as $p)
   @foreach($p->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->comments }}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, remove

```
$comments = post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

from `show()` function.(don't forget to delete `'comments'` from `compact()` too)

now, add this in your view file:

```
@foreach($post->comments->orderBy('created_at', 'desc') as $comment)
   {{ $comment->title... }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: some thing still i missing i getting this error

Method orderBy does not exist. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\new\resources\views\post\show.blade.php)